# nightwatch Error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory .../examples/pages"

Tags: node.js, automation, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am starting to use nightwatch (followed this tutorial -
 https://blog.risingstack.com/end-to-end-testing-with-nightwatch-js-node-js-at-scale/)

I created a folder in "/Users/luisfranqueira/fyde/experiments"
And inside I have the structure: 
/bin /reports /tests nightwatch.json

when running the tests follow all instructions in the tutorial - I run the command "npm run test-e2e"

I get the following error:

```
> @ test-e2e /Users/luisfranqueira
> nightwatch


There was an error while starting the test runner:

Error: Cannot read source folder: /Users/luisfranqueira/examples/tests
    at /Users/luisfranqueira/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js:203:21
    at /Users/luisfranqueira/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/walk.js:97:18
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ test-e2e: `nightwatch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ test-e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/luisfranqueira/.npm/_logs/2017-12-05T12_23_49_345Z-debug.log
```

**I know that this is probably a miss configured path, however, I don't know where to change it....**

Comment: Are you in the right directory when trying to launch the tests? You mentioned the tests are in `/Users/luisfranqueira/fyde/experiments` but nightwatch is looking for them in `/Users/luisfranqueira/examples/tests`. Make sure you are in the correct directory and that the src path in the nightwatch config is set correctly.

Comment: It helped! Thanks for the tip! :)